# Adding the sum of a multi dimensional number array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

this may seem like a given but I want an answer where I only use what I believe to be functional programming... so no `for()` loops. Say I have a multi dimensional array which contains arrays of numbers and numbers only! Something like this:

```
var numberArray = [[1,5,12],[1,-1], [5,11,45,-3],[0,1,2] ... ];
```

Now instead of having nested loops I would like to use `.forEach` and / or `.reduce` to get the sum of all numbers in `numberArray`, however I would also like to perform an action so that any negative numbers are omitted or given the value 0 when doing the addition. I thought something like this would work:

```
numberArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

but I am not sure how to perform the action to set negative numbers to 0 (or just omit them) and then get the sum...

Comment: Mark down but no reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) twice.

```js
var numberArray = [[1, 5, 12], [1, -1], [5, 11, 45, -3], [0, 1, 2]],
    sum = numberArray.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return a.reduce(function (s, b) {
            return b > 0 ? s + b : s;
        }, r);
    }, 0);

document.write(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do reduce twice.

Try this

```
numberArray.reduce(function(prev,current){return prev.concat(current)}).reduce(function(prev,current){return prev+current});
```

**DEMO**

```js
    var numberArray = [[1,5,12],[1,-1], [5,11,45,-3],[0,1,2]];
    var output = numberArray.reduce(function(prev,current){return prev.concat(current)}).reduce(function(prev,current){return prev+current});
    document.body.innerHTML += output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an nested `reduce` at this context,

```
var numberArray = [[1,5,12],[1,-1], [5,11,45,-3],[0,1,2]]
var x = numberArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b.reduce(function(c,d){
       return c + ((d > 0) ? d : 0);
    }, 0);
}, 0);
console.log(x); //206
```

Comment: I didn't think of using a nested .reduce!

Comment: @MarkSandman Yeah. If you do concat inside of a reduce, then that will also be considered as an iteration. So `NxN + N` will become the running time. But if you use nested reduce, the running time would be `NxN`. we have to consider about performance while using functional programming features.